# How to merge row in the first column in LaTeX

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to create table like this in Latex.

[image]

This is my script for create table.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|} \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{DEF}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ ABC} \\ \hline
A&B&C\\ \hline
1& 4 & 7 \\ \hline
2& 5 & 8 \\ \hline
3& 6 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I run this script it show error like this.

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.<template> \endtemplate ...row{3}{}{DEF}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ ABC}
```

How to create table like this picture?

Comment: Hey, and welcome to tex.SX. Please provide compilable code (i.e. with `\begin{document}`. This will make it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decipher the following template.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\let\mc=\multicolumn
\let\mr=\multirow
\let\cl=\cline

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*6{c|}l}
\cl{3-6}
\mc{2}{c|}{\mr{2}{*}{empty}} & \mc{4}{c|}{Primes} \\\cl{3-6}
\mc{2}{c|}{}                 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\\cl{1-6}
\mr{2}{*}{Powers}            & 504 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\\cl{2-6}
                             & 540 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\\cl{1-6}
\mr{2}{*}{Powers}            & HCF & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & min \\\cl{2-6}
                             & LCM & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & max \\\cl{1-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Warning

`\mr` can be nested in `\mc` but the reverse is not possible!

## References

My code above was inspired by an example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) as follows.

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l}
\cline{3-6}
& & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Primes} \\ \cline{3-6}
& & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers} } &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{504} & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 &     \\ \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{540} & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &     \\ \cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers} } &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{gcd} & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & min \\ \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & max \\ \cline{1-6}
\end{tabular}
```

However, as you can see and compare, my code is much much simpler and well refactored yet still readable, right?

Answer (score 3):

What you try to do can be done with this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c} \hline
& & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ ABC} \\ \hline
& & A&B&C\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{DEF} & D &1& 4 & 7 \\ \cline{2-5}
&E&  2& 5 & 8 \\ \cline{2-5}
&F&  3& 6 & 9 \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But! LaTeX can make tables that are much nicer that this Excel-style layout. Consider doing something like this, which still nice to look at if you have more than 3 columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{ ABC} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ ABC} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
& A&B&C & A2&B2&C2\\ \midrule
DEF:\\
\;D &1& 4 & 7 &1& 4 & 7 \\ 
\;E&  2& 5 & 8 &1& 4 & 7 \\ 
\;F&  3& 6 & 9 &1& 4 & 7 \\ 
XYZ:\\
\;X &1& 4 & 7 &1& 4 & 7  \\ 
\;Y&  2& 5 & 8 &1& 4 & 7 \\ 
\;Z&  3& 6 & 9 &1& 4 & 7  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\multirow` command, needs to be act on its own column... 
So you need to add an extra column on the left side in each column and thus an extra `&` needed  on each left side of every row of your table and an extra columntype (lets say `c`) at the beginning of your tabular's arguments.

Also, multicolumn in your example will should be 3 rows tall and should start from the row (1,4,7). But then an `\hline` on one of this or the next rows, would add a line in the "multirowed" cell too, and this is not wanted. So, we have to change some `\hline`s with `\cline{2-4}` that is a line from column 2 to column 4 and not from 1st to last.

Finally, you can add empty `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` as first element of your first two rows, in order to change their behavior from `|c|` to `c|` and remove this way the unwanted vertical line from their left side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|} \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ ABC} \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&A&B&C\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{DEF}&1& 4 & 7 \\ \cline{2-4}
&2& 5 & 8 \\ \cline{2-4}
&3& 6 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

PS: Tried to show you what was your mistakes and not to find a way to show your table more beautiful.

[image]